# Replacing bathroom vanity light fixture

Tags: light-fixture

I’m currently replacing a bathroom light fixture that previously had three light bulbs for a light fixture that now has only two. The issue I’m having is that the junction box only has one neutral wire and one positive wire and one ground wire however my new light fixture has two neutral wires and two positive wires one for each light bulb. How do I connect all of the wires together ( please only use simple terms)

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Answer (score 1):

If either your light fixture has its own switches, or if you want to control both bulbs together with a single wall-switch, then wire your fixture like this:

- Connect all three neutral wires together with a wirenut
- Connect all three live (positive) wires together with a wirenut
- If the junction box is made out of metal, connect the ground wire there. If the fixture has a place to connect a ground, connect that also to the metal box..
- If the junction box is made out of plastic, if the fixture has a place to connect a ground, connect the ground wire there, otherwise cap-off the ground wire.

Comment: You are assuming the OP is in North America. If he/she is in Europe/Asia/etc, this advice may be wrong.

Comment: @DoxyLover, what North American assumptions do you see in the answer? The only part that would not be valid for my own location (Netherlands, Europe) is the possibility of having a metal junction box.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t aware that Europe used wirenuts. I thought that was a US thing.